# Give an example of a function from $X$ to $Y$

Tags: combinatorics

Give an example of a function from $X = \{1,2,3\}$ to $Y = \{0,1\}$. Let $F$ denote the set of all functions $f: X \rightarrow Y$. Show that $|F|=8$, by listing the members of $F$.

My solution:

a function from $X$ to $Y$ refers generally to an element $x$ in $X$ assigned to an element $y = f (x)$ in $Y$.

So, we are going to find every possible function values ​​that can be obtained. One example is that $f(1) = 0$, $f(2) = 0$ and $f(3)=1$. Then it's just to find 7 other functions in the same way?

Comment: What are you stuck on?  Do you understand what a function is?

Comment: Yes i know. I forget to post my solution :)

Comment: What is $f(3)$ in your example?

Comment: it is equal to 1.

Comment: As further practice, you might try to figure out how many functions $g : Y \rightarrow X$ there are.

Comment: hmm..

g(0)=1 or g(0)=2 or g(0)=3 and same for g(1). Therefore it can be 3x3 = 9 unique functions ?

Comment: That's correct!

Comment: nice! :) thanks for the help. It was a pretty easy exercise but I just started to read algebra&combinatoric.

Comment: Now, you can also go for $h:Y\rightarrow Y$ and $p: X\rightarrow X$.

Comment: 4 unique functions h and 27 for p ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(1)$ can be equal to $0$ or $1$, $f(2)$ can be equal to $0$ or $1$, and similarly $f(3)$ can be equal to $0$ or $1$. Thus there are $2 \times  2 \times 2 = 8$ unique functions. Here is a list:

$$000, 001, 010, 011, 100, 101, 110, 111$$

Where, for example, $010$ means that $f(1) = 0, f(2) = 1, f(3) = 0$

Comment: Thanks! seems that i did right. But now I know how they find how many unique functions there is.